# Regular expression to find the closest pattern match to an html tag

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I am checking for a solution to the following problem.
I have a text sequence as follows and I would like to extract the contents of the square brackets which is closer to the `<em>` tag.

```
[P1/1]0(4)0(5)**[P1/432]** g(5)I(2)d(7)a(8)`<em>`b(5)[P1/4]C(6)e(7)B(8)B`</em>`(9)[P1/5]0(6)i(7)[P1/6]0(1)I(2)[P1/7]0(6)[P1/1]0(1)0(2)[P1/2]E(1)c(2)d(3)a(4)**[P1/3]** 0(1)`<em>`b(2)[P1/4]C(1)e(2)B(3)B`</em>`(4)[P1/5]0(1)
```

So in the above mentioned text, what I am searching for is **[P1/432]** and **[P1/3]**.

With regular expression `((.(?!\[.*?]))+?)<em>`, I am not able to get only the contents of the brackets, but everything from [ to `<em>`.

Can someone help me ??

Comment: Isn't `[P1/4]` closer than `[P1/3]` to `<em>` on counting characters between?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was searching for the content to the left side of <em> tag (I forgot to mention).

Answer (score 1):

There is a straightforward solution if we don't care about nested, unbalanced brackets:

```
\[[^\]\[]*\](?=[^\]\[]*<em>)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/N4T1v0/1)